# Is there a way to pull out object from array and into a new array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Given:**

```
myObjArray = [ [ [ [Object] ] ], [ [ [Object] ] ], [ [ [Object] ] ] ]
```

**Desired Result**

```
[{Object},{Object},{Object}]
```

So is there a way to pull the [Object(s)] out of the array and into a new one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array.prototype.map` with a recursive function which retrieve the object from the nested arrays:

```js
var arr = [ [ [ [ { prop: 'val1' }] ] ], [ [ [{ prop: 'val2' }] ] ], [ [ [{ prop: 'val3' }] ] ] ];

var res = arr.map(getObject);

function getObject(o) {
    return Array.isArray(o) ?  getObject(o[0]) : o;
}
console.log(res);
```